# Best structure to put a Table in (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

In a Widget Function I return a Column and then add a few rows to display some text and data.

I want to add a Table that is shown below the textrows and they should look like in the picture below. The Table should also scale itself to be able to fit into smaller screens. Which Object/function should I use to achieve this look while being able to integrate it into the return of my widget function?

[image: Table Structure I want to add]

Code:

```
return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
      child:
        Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
              cell(Text("Time:", textAlign: TextAlign.right)),
              cell(Text(getCatchableTime())),
            ]),
            Row(
              children: [
              cell(Text("Location:", textAlign: TextAlign.right)),
              cell(Text(location(locale))),
            ]),
            Row(children: [
              cell(Text("Price:", textAlign: TextAlign.right)),
              cell(Text("$price ★")),
            ]),
            Row(
              children: [
              cell(Text("Size:", textAlign: TextAlign.right)),
              cell(Text(getShadowsize(localization))),
            ]),
          ],
        ),
        
      );
```

Comment: You can use the Data Table for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Flutter's material design data table. The widget allows you to build a table
that automatically sizes its columns
according to what's in the cells.

First, add the DataTable() widget
and define its columns.
Next, define each row
and the cells in each of them.
And voila, you have a DataTable.

But wait, there's more.
You can show how the table is sorted.
You can make a column numerical,
forcing right alignment
in left to right locales.
You can show that a row is selected.
You can show that a cell is editable
or not yet filled in.

All the elements of the DataTable
provide friendly callbacks,
so you can implement how the user
should edit, select, or sort the data.
Also, don't forget
that everything is a widget.
So, feel free to put any widget
into your data cells.

If it's possible
that all of your data
won't fit in the horizontal space,
for example, on small phones,
wrap the widget
with a SingleChildScrollView.

Displaying data in a table is expensive, because to lay out the table all the data must be measured twice, once to negotiate the dimensions to use for each column, and once to actually lay out the table given the results of the negotiation.

For this reason, if you have a lot of data (say, more than a dozen rows with a dozen columns, though the precise limits depend on the target device), it is suggested that you use a PaginatedDataTable which automatically splits the data into multiple pages.